# why and how google puts hmlt files on my server?

Tags: godaddy, google

Why google puts html files on my server? I didn't allow it to do this thing as far i remember.

On my webserver(hosted by godaddy) i have some googledigits.html files.

Why and who they did that?

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics requires that file be there so the person hosting the site is aware and approves of Google tracking it's visitors.

Per Zordache's point, Google didn't put the file there. They only require it to be there. Your host, configuration software, or someone who has access put the file there.

Comment: That may be required for Google to work, but I can't believe that Google itself actually put the file there.  Though I would easily believe it came from some web-based control panel.